# Set E type sizes equal to each other

Tags: java, multiset

How can I set the lengths (not the data as it has already been done) of the E type arrays, _size and arr.length equal to each other? Aliasing them does not work since I keep getting an `OutOfBoundsException`. _size is of length 16 and the length of the multi set.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void fromArray(E[] arr) {

     int len = arr.length;

     int i = 0;

     _size =  arr.length;
     while (i < _size && i < len) {
         _store[i] = arr[i];
         i++;
     }
}
```

Declaration of _store and _size

```
public class ArrayMultiSet<E> implements Collection<E> {

  private static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 16;

 private E[] _store;

  private int _size;
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong. Is the actual code that throws the exception? What are _store and _size declared?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Where's the multiset you mention? is it _store? How do you define it? When you get an OutOfBoundsException, what does the message say?

Comment: You can't change the length of `_istore` unless you reassign it. `_istore = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length); _size = arr.length;` would be easiest way to implement this whole method.

Comment: @Gintoki, I am downvoting your question until you clarify it.

Comment: No it is the JUnit that is throwing the exception. A test is checking the length ares actually the same. For instance when arr.length is 45 it should instead be set to _size. Yes, _store is the multi set.

Comment: Someone else said "You need to set the size of your new array properly ... depending on the size of arr." Can someone help clarify that?